# Can a ROC AUC curve look like this?

Tags: regression, spss, modeling, roc

What are the possible shapes of an ROC curve? Is it necessary for an ROC curve to be shaped like a normal distribution curve?

Can we regard the following two curves as ROC with the area under the curve equal to 0.925 and 0.950, respectively?

[image: ROC with 0.925 area under curve]

[image: ROC with 0.925 area under curve]

Comment: You might state your ultimate goal, and how ROC curves provide insights (if they do) towards meeting that goal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Valid ROC curves must be monotonically increasing, start at $(0,0)$ and arrive at $(1,1)$, that's about it. Both shown curves are valid.